# Adding things to the user PATH | Powershell SETX Error

Tags: windows, powershell

How would you ***add*** (not change) to the user PATH variable using `setx`?

I am trying the following:

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\bearc\Downloads\pathTesting"
```

But it only changes the whole path variable to the system path, then the path just added e.g pathTesting.

How would I add to this variable and not change it?

Eventually I will add this to my C# program but yeah.

Thanks,
Henry.

Comment: I hope the linked post provides a solution, but the short of it is: avoid `setx` for updating the `Path` environment variable and, generally, any environment variables based on `REG_EXPAND_SZ` registry values.